# How do I properly loop through this context dictionary in Django?

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I'm trying to loop through a nested context dictionary where I'm missing something, The dictionary I'm working on is,

```
output =
    {
        'results': {

            'result2': {

                'name': 'Alex',
                'roll': 5,
                'phone': 'not provided',
                'email': 'blah@blah.blah',
                'grade': 8,
            },

            'result0': {

                'name': 'John',
                'roll': 23,
                'phone': 'not provided',
                'email': 'blah@blah.blah',
                'grade': 8,
            },

            'result1': {

                'name': 'Mike',
                'roll': 35,
                'phone': 'not provided',
                'email': 'blah@blah.blah',
                'grade': 8,
            }
        },
        'status' : 'ok',
    }
```

with a simple loop,

```
{% for result in results %}
    {{ result }}
{% endfor %}
```

where the results are `result2`, `result0` and `result1`,

changing results to `{{result.name}}` to access the values, renders nothing.

How to do I render the values using the key?

thanks.

Comment: Don't you mean `result.name`, not `results.name`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe `result.name` sorry typo. fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`results` is a dictionary, and looping through a dictionary gives you the keys. To loop through the values, say so explicitly:

```
{% for result in results.values %}
    {{ result }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you want the key and the value, you can do that too, with `items`:

```
{% for key, value in results.items %}
    {# ... #}
{% endfor %}
```